# use old helper in nestead inputs

Tags: php, laravel, helper

I am using laravel and I have input like this

```
<input value="{{ old('group[1][p_id]') }}" type="text" class="form-control inputfield min-width-140" name="group[1][p_id]" placeholder=" 30">
```

but whenever I want to use old helper it does not work well

how can I use old helper in this case?

Comment: Try `group.1.p_id` or `group.0.p_id` instead of `group[1][p_id]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a field with the name `group[1][p_id]` you use `old('group.1.p_id')`.

When `p_id` is a dynamic field and your input field name is like `group[1][3]` you can use old like `old('group.1.' . $p_id)`.